# Telerik RadGrid group header alignment (with static grid headers)?

Tags: asp.net, header, telerik, grouping, radgrid

The group headers in my RadGrid align properly when I don't use static headers, but when I do, they get out of alignment. Can't seem to find anything that fixes this. Relevant code, unimportant details omitted:

```
<telerik:RadGrid runat="server" ID="RadGrid1" GridLines="None" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowMultiRowSelection="True" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource">
    <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="PageID">
        <GroupHeaderTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbGroupHeader"/>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblGroupHeader" Text='<%# (((GridGroupHeaderItem)Container).AggregatesValues["Group"]) %>'/>
        </GroupHeaderTemplate>

        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridClientSelectColumn HeaderStyle-Width="2.5%"/>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PageName" HeaderText="Page Name" UniqueName="PageName"/>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PageID" Display="False" ReadOnly="True" UniqueName="PageID"
            ...
        </Columns>

        <GroupByExpressions>
            <telerik:GridGroupByExpression>
                <GroupByFields>
                    <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldName="Order"/>
                </GroupByFields>
                <SelectFields>
                    <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldName="Group"/>
                </SelectFields>
            </telerik:GridGroupByExpression>
        </GroupByExpressions>
    </MasterTableView>

    <ClientSettings AllowKeyboardNavigation="True" AllowColumnsReorder="True" ReorderColumnsOnClient="False">
        <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True"/>
        <Resizing AllowColumnResize="True" ResizeGridOnColumnResize="False" ClipCellContentOnResize="True" EnableRealTimeResize="True" AllowResizeToFit="True"/>
        <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" SaveScrollPosition="True"/>
    </ClientSettings>
</telerik:radGrid>
```

Pictures (imgur):

[UseStaticHeaders="False"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCwqQ.jpg)

[UseStaticHeaders="True"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRSol.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into a similar issue.

The site I'm working has has radGrids, which are re-sized when the browser window is re-sized.  The radGrid header looked normal when the browser window size was small, but became misaligned as the browser size increased.

I have UseStaticHeaders set to "true" and TableLayout set to "fixed".  I'm also using specific Header Widths instead of percentages.

When re-sizing radGrids, its best to leave off the width of one column.  I noticed this wasn't the case on the grid I was working on.  When I removed one column's width, the headers immediately aligned correctly.

I'm not sure if this solution will work for you, but it worked for me.

**UPDATE**

Here's the markup for one of the grid's I've been working on:

```
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="grdItems" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="grdItems_NeedDataSource" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" Height="100%"
        GridLines="None" EnableOutsideScripts="True" PagerStyle-AlwaysVisible="true" PagerStyle-Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="250" 
        AllowSorting="true" OnItemCreated="grdItems_ItemCreated" OnItemCommand="grdItems_ItemCommand" OnPreRender="grdItems_PreRender" TabIndex="17"
        OnItemDataBound="grdItems_ItemDataBound" >
        <ClientSettings AllowColumnsReorder="true" ReorderColumnsOnClient="true" ColumnsReorderMethod="reorder">
            <Selecting AllowRowSelect="False" />
            <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" />
            <Resizing AllowColumnResize="True" ClipCellContentOnResize="true" EnableRealTimeResize="true" ResizeGridOnColumnResize="true" />
        </ClientSettings>
        <MasterTableView CommandItemDisplay="Top" ClientDataKeyNames="ei_pk" DataKeyNames="ei_pk,ei_eco_fk" AllowAutomaticInserts="True" GridLines="None" TableLayout="fixed" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
            <CommandItemTemplate>
                <a href="#" onclick="return ShowAddForm();"><asp:Image ID="AddItem" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/RadControls/Grid/Skins/Office2007/AddRecord.gif" AlternateText="Add Item" /><asp:Label ID="lblAddItem" runat="server" Text="Add Item" /></a>
            </CommandItemTemplate> 
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="Edit" Visible="False" Resizable="false" Reorderable="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>                           
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="EditLink" runat="server" Text="Edit" ImageUrl="../RadControls/Grid/Skins/Office2007/Edit.gif" />                                
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle Width="20" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>    
                <telerik:GridButtonColumn Resizable="false" Reorderable="false" ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to delete this item?" UniqueName="Delete" CommandName="Delete" Visible="False" ButtonType="ImageButton" ImageUrl="../RadControls/Grid/Skins/Office2007/Delete.gif">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="20"/>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                </telerik:GridButtonColumn> 
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Trade" DataField="ftr_description" UniqueName="ftr_description" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Cost Type" DataField="combined_itemType" UniqueName="combined_itemType" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Est. Type" DataField="etp_code" UniqueName="etp_code" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Item Code" DataField="combined_code" UniqueName="combined_code" />
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Quantity" DataField="ei_quantity" UniqueName="ei_quantity">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="50" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>                       
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Unit Cost" DataField="ei_unitCostworking" UniqueName="ei_unitCostworking" >
                    <HeaderStyle Width="75" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Total Cost" DataField="ei_extendedCostWorking" UniqueName="ei_extendedCostWorking" DataFormatString="{0:#0.00}">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="80" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>                            
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Budget" DataField="ei_budgetworking" UniqueName="ei_budgetworking">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="80" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn HeaderText="Change Order" DataTextField="eco_number" UniqueName="eco_number" DataNavigateUrlFields="eco_number" SortExpression="eco_number">
                    <HeaderStyle Width="104" />
                </telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn>
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Comment: My table layout is set to the default, which I assume is auto. I had HeaderStyle-Width set as percentages, but I tried leaving one off and it still didn't fix it :(

Comment: @justaguy Unless you have a reason for leaving the TableLayout as the default, you might try setting it to "fixed".

Comment: Changed to fixed with specific widths, then with one left off, still no go.

Comment: @justaguy I updated my answer with the markup from one of my grids.

Comment: Tried moving the HeaderStyle out of the inline version (HeaderStyle-Width), because that was pretty much the only difference, but that still didn't work. HorizontalAlign no go either. I suspect it's something in the CSS somewhere. Maybe something in the skin we're using.